# How to access each node in an array of nodes in Puppet

Tags: arrays, nodes, puppet

I'm very new to puppet so I hope you can help me with what will no doubt be a simple issue?

I have an array of nodes as follows:

```
$nodesArray =   ['abc123.server.domain.net',
            'bcd234.server.domain.net',
            'cde345.server.domain.net',
            'def456.server.domain.net',
            'efg567.server.domain.net',
            'fgh678.server.domain.net',]
```

And I am simply trying to access each node using Puppet's node definition so that I can install apps on each node.

```
$nodesArray.each| $individualNode | {
        node $individualNode {
               exec { 'install app':
                     command =>      '<command to install app>',
               }
        }
 }
```

Despite trying different things, I continually get the error:

> Error: Could not parse for environment production: Syntax error at 'individualNode ' (file: /root/script.pp, line: 59, column: 7) on node abc123.server.domain.net

The error message points to the *'node $individualNode {'* line, but I don't see what I'm doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to declare multiple nodes with the same content then just exercise the ability to do so directly:

```
node 'abc123.server.domain.net',
     'bcd234.server.domain.net',
     'cde345.server.domain.net',
     'def456.server.domain.net',
     'efg567.server.domain.net',
     'fgh678.server.domain.net' {
  exec { 'install app':
    command =>      '<command to install app>',
  }
}
```

Do be aware, however, that Puppet will match at most one node definition to each node, so it would not be effective to list any node in more than one such construct.

Generally speaking, however, one puts resource declarations such as your `Exec` into *classes* in *modules*, and then uses one or more of the mechanisms available to specify which classes to apply to each node.  The approach presented in the question is more or less inside out.

Comment: Thank you @John Bollinger.  That solution worked, though I'm surprised that using node definitions through arrays didn't?  And I have taken onboard your point about using classes.  Thanks again.